# Which question to flag?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've come across a user who seems to have a habit of reposting questions when he doesn't get an answer or one he likes.

I've flagged one of the duplicates, but I'm not sure which to flag out of this pair:

[get picture size by distance - augmented reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137699/get-picture-size-by-distance-augmented-reality)

[Augmented reality - Image size transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387535/augmented-reality-image-size-transform)

The first is the earlier question, but the second is a (slightly) better question and has a better answer.

Which question should be flagged? The newer one or the "worse" one?

**Edit**:

He went for a hat-trick:

[scale object size from camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014207/scale-object-size-from-camera)

Comment: Since they're from the same user, I'd edit any extra detail from the later question into the first, and flag for a Merge which deletes the newer question and moves it's answer onto the old one

Comment: @BenBrocka Is that via a flag for moderator attention?

Comment: @deadly Flag as "other", and explain the situation.

Comment: Yeah, you have to use an Other flag, ask for a Merge; the mods will know what it means. It's rare, but pretty much exactly for this situation (same user reposts same question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they're the same question in intent they should be **merged** which combines the two questions (deleting one of them) and migrating all answers to the same place.

Edit the extra information from the later question into the older one and flag the question with an "other" flag and explain the questions are the exact same by the same person and should be merged together.